# How to reading multiple barcodes from an image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, image, barcode

I'm working on a Flutter project where I need to read about 30 barcodes from a single image at once. However, I have not been able to find a suitable package that can do this for me. As a workaround, I have attempted to split the image into 30 smaller and equal parts and read the barcodes from each part individually.

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to accomplish this task in Flutter, ideally without having to split the image into multiple parts. Are there any existing packages or libraries that can handle reading multiple barcodes from a single image, or is there a way to adapt existing barcode scanning packages to handle this use case?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_zxing ? From the feature list: Scan multiple barcodes at once from the camera stream (on mobile platforms only), image file or URL

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.